# Webkit debugging tools

Tags: iphone, mobile-webkit

What tools can I use to debug mobile webkit sites?
Is there a better tool than "Firebug for iPhone" or is "Firebug for iPhone" pretty much the best tool out there?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Safari and its developer tools? You can set your User-Agent string to an iPhone's user agent string and work from there. Besides, you get full access to the standard WebKit's develoepr tools.

Comment: Thanks zneak, that's great way to do it. Is there anyway I can simulate orientation using the Safari and it's developer tool route? Thanks, Tee

Comment: @teepusink: I have to agree I never thought about the need to do this with web development. It's a bit of a convoluted way, but you can, from the inspector, apply the `-webkit-transform` CSS property to rotate the body to 90 degrees: `-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, [Weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) is the best thing out there:

A client/server solution that hooks into Safari or (better) Chrome's developer tools.